# Create readonly mongoose/mongodb connection or protect schema from modifying/deleting object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an application that connects to an existing database and retrieves some data from it. This app will use this database in read-only mode. Despite it is our code I would like to add 'fool-level' protection from modifying/deleting documents accidentally by other developers/myself in the future. Tried with [pre hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining) but it looks that there're different `remove` hooks, query, model, document, etc...  But I couldn't achieve consistency in behavior for all types of removing queries, query, model, document, etc...
Is there any appropriate solution to this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a read-only user and connect through that user:
https://sysadmins.co.za/create-read-only-users-in-mongodb/